# How can I re-render my component when a property to it changes (webcomponents)

Tags: javascript, web-component

Here is my submit button component:

```
class SubmitButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
        this.isLoading = this.getAttribute('loading') === 'true';
        console.log('isLoading: ', this.isLoading);
        this.button = `<button>Go</button>`;
        this.spinner = `
            <svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
                <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
            </svg>`
    this.innerHTML = `
      <style>      
            button {
                margin-left: 1rem;
            }

            .spinner {
              // animations and stuff
            }
      </style>
            ${this.isLoading ? this.spinner : this.button}
`;
  }
}

customElements.define("submit-button", SubmitButton);
```

I'm calling it with `<submit-botton loading="true"></submit-button>` however when I dynamically change the property with js (ie: fetch finishes), the button does not re-render itself.

Is there anyway to get it to re-render?

I'm changing the value of the property with this code:

```
const button = document.querySelector('submit-button');
button.loading = true;
// do some fetching
button.loading = false;
```

Edit: here is an update using changedAttributes handler but it still doesn't work:

```
class SubmitButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
        this.isLoading = this.getAttribute('loading') === 'true';
  }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['loading'];
    }

     get loading() {
             return this.isLoading;
     }

     set loading(val) {
            this.isLoading = val === 'true';
     }

    render() {
        this.button = `<button>Go</button>`;
        this.spinner = `
            <svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
                <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
            </svg>`
    this.innerHTML = `
      <style>      
            button {
                margin-left: 1rem;
            }

            .spinner {
                animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
                z-index: 2;
                width: 4rem;
                height: 4rem;
                margin-left: 1rem;
            }

            .path {
                stroke: #633;
                stroke-linecap: round;
                animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
            }

            @keyframes rotate {
                100% {
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }

            @keyframes dash {
                0% {
                    stroke-dasharray: 1, 150;
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                }
                50% {
                    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
                    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
                }
                100% {
                    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
                    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
                }
            }
      </style>
            ${this.isLoading ? this.spinner : this.button}
`;

    }

  connectedCallback() {
        console.log('isLoading: ', this.isLoading);
        this.render();
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log('attr changed: ',name, oldValue, newValue);
        this.render();
  }
}

customElements.define("submit-button", SubmitButton);
```

Comment: Myay be a getter + setter can help you. Instead of properties you can define a getter and a setter for them. And in setter call a function, which will recount your `innerHTML` (as it was made in vue2)

Comment: I'm not using vue

Comment: I just say that  vue uses same logic with its `data` `computed` and `props`

Comment: Create `_loading` property, getter `get loading() {return this._loading}` and a setter `set loading(value) {this._loading = value; this.refreshTemplate()}`. Where `refreshTemplate` is a method that will rewrite `innerHTML` like you defined it in `connectedCallback`

Comment: Read The Fine Manual; and learn about ``observedAttributes`` https://javascript.info/custom-elements And don't forget **properties** are not **attributes**; So your ``.loading`` needs a getter/setter in your class.

Comment: How do I use this `observerdAttributes`

Comment: I have updated question with new code....still doesnj't work

Comment: @chovy setter also should update your template. Call `render` method in your setter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was fun, thanks for asking the question. I borrowed some code from https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements and created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/sxrL75aq/).

Basically, I didn't worry about whether `loading` was `"true"` or `"false"`, merely checked for the existence of the attribute:

```
get loading() {
  return this.hasAttribute('loading');
}

set loading(val) {
  if (val) {
    this.setAttribute('loading', '');
  } else {
    this.removeAttribute('loading');
  }
}
```

After that, it was a matter of checking `this.loading`. Please do check the JSFiddle though.

Comment: even easier. boolean attributes are all we need here.